# Is there a list of Google Docs Equation Editor symbol names such as "\alpha"?

Tags: google-docs

In Google Docs, you can insert an equation and edit it with the equation editor. You can add symbols like summations, integrals, and greek letters with the equation editor, but it is also possible to add them by typing "\sum" "\hat", "\alpha", etc into the equation.

Does Google provide a list of all of these keywords somewhere? It doesn't follow Latex, or the names of the symbols when you go to Insert>"Insert special characters". A lot of keywords that you would expect to work like "\integral" or "\capitaldelta" do not work.

It's a useful feature, but I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found an interesting one at http://www.notuom.com/google-docs-equation-shortcuts.html
For later reference, a protected copy is also available at https://web.archive.org/web/20180625063351/http://www.notuom.com/google-docs-equation-shortcuts.html

So there are at least all these tags available:
**letters:** \alpha
\beta
\gamma
\delta
\epsilon
\varepsilon
\zeta
\eta
\theta
\vartheta
\iota
\kappa
\lambda
\mu
\nu
\xi
\pi
\varpi
\rho
\varrho
\sigma
\varsigma
\tau
\upsilon
\phi
\varphi
\chi
\psi
\omega
\Gamma
\Delta
\Theta
\Lambda
\Xi
\Pi
\Sigma
\Upsilon
\Phi
\Psi
\Omega
**ops:** \times
\div
\cdot
\pm
\mp
\ast
\star
\circ
\bullet
\oplus
\ominus
\oslash
\otimes
\odot
\dagger
\ddagger
\vee
\wedge
\cap
\cup
\aleph
\Re
\Im
\top
\bot
\infty
\partial
\forall
\exists
\neg
\triangle
\diamond
**relations:** \leq
\geq
\prec
\succ
\preceq
\succeq
\ll
\gg
\equiv
\sim
\simeq
\asymp
\approx
\ne
\subset
\supset
\subseteq
\supseteq
\in
\ni
\notin
**maths:** \frac
\sqrt
\rootof
\subsuperscript
\subscript or _
\superscript or ^
\overline
\widehat
\bigcapab
\bigcupab
\prodab
\coprodab
\rbracelr
\sbracelr
\bracelr
\abs
\intab
\ointab
\sumab
\limab
**arrows:** \leftarrow
\rightarrow
\leftrightarrow
\Leftarrow
\Rightarrow
\Leftrightarrow
\uparrow
\downarrow
\updownarrow
\Uparrow
\Downarrow
\Updownarrow
**binomial:** \choose

Comment: With all the symbols it would be quite long to copy it here, but I added a web archive copy of the link to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [all LaTeX commands](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols) with [Auto-LaTeX Equations in Google Docs/Slides](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/autolatex_equations/850293439076?utm_source=tutorialWebsite), and as a plus they look way better too. \integral would be \int for instance, and there are more choices [here](https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php).

Comment: but what if we want to use google slides?

Comment: Yes, it also works on Google Slides